# Regex 4 Digit from string phonenumber

Tags: regex, go

I want to take the first 4 numbers of the string phone numbers

example

```
phoneNumber := "081911254966"
```

I want to get from regex Go and get the result "0819"

Comment: Do you really need regex? `string(phoneNumber[:4])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    phoneNumber := "081911254966"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^\d{4}`).FindString(phoneNumber)
    r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`\d{4}`).FindString("trash text 081911254966 trash text")
    // if not need regexp
    fmt.Println(phoneNumber[:4])
    fmt.Println(r)
    fmt.Println(r2)
}
```

```
0819
0819
0819
```